"Es gibt..." versus "Da gibt es..." What is the difference?
In my reading this sentenced appears:

Was Frauen betrifft, da gibt es nur dich.

Why is it not this?

Was Frauen betrifft, gibt es nur dich.

Many other examples could be provided, but none make it clear what the "da" provides, that is not already provided by the relative clause.

In the second example you have a normal sentence structure with the topic "was...betrifft" as the first item of a main clause (a verbsecond-clause).
The first example has a dangling topic: it is followed by a complete clause with the verb in second position, and a demonstrative "da" in first position.

[Was Frauen betrifft] [1-Da 2-gibt es nur dich]
[1-Was Frauen betrifft, 2-gibt es nur dich]

So there is a small break between the two parts, topic and main clause. German grammar calls this "Linksversetzung". The effect is in this example to emphasise the main clause somewhat more: it is like stopping and thinking and then blurting out what you feel. This grammatical construction is also somewhat more colloquial.
The "da" is a filler for the first position of a main clause, but it is more of a demonstrative than the usual filler "es" – you could say it refers to "the situation at hand" (a little bit like English "There is no one like you", although the English there-construction has a more specialised meaning). This demonstrative "da" is needed here to take up the first, dangling item (while simple "es" would close off the main clause, so to speak, the dummy "es" is not pronominal).
