Subordinated clause
"Why isn't 'studiere' right after the comma in 'wer die Menschen kennenlernen will, der studiere ihre Entschuldigungen' when it's the second clause?"

The quoted sentence is ok. Can you elaborate a bit more, what exactly is your question?

It is pretty much analogous to this issue:  https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/77995/es-gibt-versus-da-gibt-es-what-is-the-difference

Thanks for your help! I actually have almost the same issue. Why it is not "Wer die Menschen kennenlernen will,studiere der ihre Entschuldigungen.

The sentence is OK, "studiere" an imperative. It is a form used similar to the Latin coniunctivus praesentis, e.g.:

eamus!

literally "we would go" but the meaning is "Let us go!" or "we should go!"
The meaning of your example is: who wants to learn to know people should study to their excuses. "kennenlernen" could be less literally translated by "verstehen" (to understand), "studieren" here is used in the meaning "to examine closely".
The main sentence, stripped of all the extras, is:

Der studiere!

Your own suggestion, "... studiere der ..." would be wrong because German is a V2-language: the verb always goes in second place in a main sentence. The "der" is acting as a "Korrelat" here: a word which stands in to mark the place where the content of the relative sentence should go. The relative sentence is:

Wer die Menschen kennenlernen will,

who wants to understand people. German has a less fixed sentence order than English and this often makes such markers necessary, although in this specific case the Korrelat could have been left out:

Wer die Menschen kennenlernen will, studiere ...

Typically "da-words" and pronouns (like here "der" - this is NOT an article although it looks like one) are used for this purpose:

Ich habe dafür gearbeitet, einmal reich zu sein.

The "dafür" marks the place the content of the relative sentence would have gone, would it have fitted into a simple object, like here:

Ich habe für Reichtum gearbeitet.

The remainder of the sentence is a simple object in Akkusativ: "ihre Entschuldigungen".

That der is a zero-position item, similar to und and aber. So it doesn't occupy a position in the field model. Position one is still occupied by the initial subordinate clause.
This whole wer …, der … construction is a zweiteiliger Konnektor. Different to the better known ones as entweder … oder, je … desto, or sowohl … als auch etc. the second part may be left out:

Wer ohne Sünde ist, (der) werfe den ersten Stein.
Was sich liebt, (das) neckt sich.
Wie man sich bettet, (so) liegt man.

If it's not left out that's because of the rhythm and often also because of emphasis.

Thanks everybody for your help.
